Mac ARM device : Rails broken - bundle not working - ovirt-engine-sdk
I'm trying to use ovirt-engine-sdk gem in my rails(6) application. bundle install is failing in my mac ARM64 machine. As per the gem documentation the gem should work with ruby 3.x versions but I'm getting the following error when I do bundle install
gem install ovirt-engine-sdk 
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib --with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ovirt-engine-sdk:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20240416-66199-2y5wag.rb extconf.rb --with-opt-dir\=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --with-ldflags\=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib --with-cflags\=-Wno-error\=implicit-function-declaration
checking for xml2-config... yes
checking for curl-config... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ov_error.c
compiling ov_http_client.c
ov_http_client.c:216:29: warning: excess elements in array initializer [-Wexcess-initializers]
        .reserved = { NULL, NULL }
                            ^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:501:9: warning: call to undeclared function 'ruby_thread_has_gvl_p'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()) {
        ^
ov_http_client.c:853:25: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CURLMcode' to different enumeration type 'CURLcode' [-Wenum-conversion]
    context_ptr->code = curl_multi_wait(context_ptr->handle, NULL, 0, timeout, NULL);
                      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:874:25: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CURLMcode' to different enumeration type 'CURLcode' [-Wenum-conversion]
    context_ptr->code = curl_multi_perform(context_ptr->handle, &pending);
                      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:1009:47: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int (VALUE, VALUE, struct curl_slist **)' (aka 'int (unsigned long, unsigned long, struct curl_slist **)') to parameter of type 'int (*)(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)' (aka 'int (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
        rb_hash_foreach(request_ptr->headers, ov_http_client_add_header, (VALUE) headers);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/intern/hash.h:33:35: note: passing argument to parameter here
void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE), VALUE);
                                  ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [ov_http_client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ljehle/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-23/3.0.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/gem_make.out


Apparently, the Ruby 3 support for this gem is still a work in progress, see the following pull request: https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby/pull/10. In fact, if you review the changes, there are some changes in the C extension, that are related to the ruby_thread_has_gvl_p function usage (that appears in your log).
In the meantime, you can point in your Gemfile, to that GitHub branch, so you'll be able to test the fix:
gem "ovirt-engine-sdk", github: "jhernand/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby", branch: "update_to_ruby_3"


This solution seems to be working - https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby/issues/11#issuecomment-2098807108

https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby/issues/14#issuecomment-2098809409 - this work around solution has worked for me
